# Using a Python 3.6 env with Spyder 5.2.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I am trying to use the package [PyCrown](https://github.com/manaakiwhenua/pycrown) which requires Python 3.6. I created a 3.6 environment with the required packages in Anaconda Prompt and then tried to use it in Spyder 5.2.2. However, it seems I cannot install a version of spyder-kernels that is compatible with both Python 3.6 and with Spyder 5.2.2.

I seem to be able to install spyder-kernels 2.1 into the env, but Spyder 5.2.2 requires spyder-kernels 2.2.

```
The Python environment or installation whose interpreter is located at
C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\envs\pycrown2‑env\python.exe
doesn't have the spyder‑kernels module or the right version of it installed (>= 2.2.1 and < 2.3.0). Without this module is not possible for Spyder to create a console for you.
```

Are there any solutions to this? This is my first foray into both Python and Spyder and I haven't been able to find the solution through a search.

Thanks, Ben